# Finding z from x and y with Gaussian function

Tags: python, location, gaussian

I have an array of 6 x and y coordinates. I want to estimate the height or z of these points in Python with the Gaussian function so that the height of two of these points is on the peak of the Gaussian function but I have no idea how to do this.
if anyone could help it would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: how are you defining height ?

Comment: also what have you tried so far ?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Height, z Gaussian function